# Conditional Where Clause Based on Sysdate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I'm creating a query that will be run twice a month:

1. On the 5th of the month looking at billing days 16-last day of the month of the previous month.

   ```
   datepart(dd,h.BILLED_DATE) > 15    
   DATEPART(mm, h.billed_date) = DATEPART(mm,dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))
   and DATEPART(yyyy, h.billed_date) = DATEPART(yyyy,dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))
   ```
2. On the 20th of the month looking at billing days of 1-15 of the same month.

   ```
   datepart(dd,h.BILLED_DATE) >= 1
   and datepart(dd,h.BILLED_DATE) < 16
   and DATEPART(mm, h.BILLED_DATE) = DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())
   and DATEPART(yyyy, h.BILLED_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()))
   ```

These work independently in the where clause.  When I try to combine them in a case statement in the where clause, however, I'm getting errors galore, starting with the first inequality after the "then."

```
Where
  Case 
    when datepart(dd,getdate()) > 15 
      then [2 above]
      else [1 above]
  End
```

Cure my ignorance.

Comment: No, I screwed up cutting and pasting.  It's fixed.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CASE is an expression that returns a single value. You can't use it for control of flow like you can in some other languages.

Your query also will not make any usage of indexes on your billed_date column, which you should consider adding to support this query.

How about this re-write, which uses pure datetime operations to build an open-ended range instead of performing all those expensive datepart functions:

```
DECLARE @today SMALLDATETIME, @start SMALLDATETIME, @end SMALLDATETIME;
SET @today = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));

SET @start = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@today), @today);
SET @end = DATEADD(DAY, 15, @start);

IF DATEPART(DAY, @today) <= 15
BEGIN
    SET @start = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @end);
    SET @end = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@today), @today);
END 

SELECT ... WHERE h.billed_date >= @start AND h.billed_date < @end;
```

Comment: what rewrite are you talking about?

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl give me a minute, please. Sorry, the editor lost all its formatting/toolbars etc. Had to log out and back in.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
WHERE (
    datepart(dd,getdate()) > 15 
    AND DATEPART(mm, enc.hosp_admsn_time) = DATEPART(mm,dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))
    AND DATEPART(yyyy, enc.hosp_admsn_time) = DATEPART(yyyy,dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))
) OR (
  datepart(dd,h.BILLED_DATE) >= 1
  and datepart(dd,h.BILLED_DATE) < 16
  and DATEPART(mm, h.BILLED_DATE) = DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())
  and DATEPART(yyyy, h.BILLED_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()))
)
```

Comment: I'm not looking for transactions from either period.  This is going to be set up to run and be delivered automatically.  If it's the run on the 5th of the month, then it needs to look for 16-last day of previous month.  If it's run on the 20th of the month, it needs to look for 1-15 of the same month.

Comment: This query will include rows from the first 15 days of this month regardless of the current date. It will also include all the rows from last month if today's date is after the 15th. Neither of these options seems like what the OP is after.

Comment: You guys are correct. I made too mechanical a change without reading deeply enough.  Point taken, lesson learned.